# a 32-bit GDI printer driver on Win 7 x64

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printer, gdi

Is there any way to get a 32-bit GDI printer driver to run on Windows 7 x64 ... or any 64-bit Windows OS?

The printer in question is a [Canon LBP 5200](http://www.canon.com.au/products/printers/laser_printers_colour/lbp5200_specs.aspx). Here is the  [driver download page](http://support-au.canon.com.au/EN/search?canonsearch=1&lang=EN&category=Printers&series=Laser+Beam+Printers+%28Colour%29&model=LASER+SHOT+LBP5200&menu=Download).

Nope, Virtual XP doesn't work.

Comment: Virtual machine works greate unless you forget to connect the printer to the guest machine. By default all devices are only connected to the host.

Comment: Does it work if the host is x64? Which host? Which VM software?

Comment: Virtual box, virtual PC and VMWare all can pass-through devices to guest. MS uses this for XP Mode on win 7 x64 for compatibility. But MS virtual PC is much worse compared to virtual box & VMWare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:  No.  For a 64-bit OS, you need 64-bit drivers.

Comment: I thought so - just thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows x64 can only handle 64 bit software (drivers, etc) at the kernel level.

Maybe if you find a compatible printer with 64 bit drivers.